# Use of "when about" as colloquial alternative to "approximately when"

Tags: colloquialisms, synonyms

If I wanted to ask someone approximately when they would be doing something, for example arriving, I could use

> **Approximately when** do you think you could do that?

Would the following be a correct and acceptable colloquial alternative?

> **When about** do you think you could do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*When about* seems rare (with the "approximately when" meaning). I did find one example in the British National Corpus from an oral history interview (formatting and punctuation added):

> And er, so what, er, what, er, sort of era was,  **when about was this**? still right at the beginning of the war when you were doing this, or ...?
>   That would have been, I would say, maybe August nineteen thirty eight.

I don't recall hearing *when about* often (eastern USA) but I am certain I've heard *when abouts*. I can't find evidence of this in any corpus I searched, but keep in mind that most of the spoken language samples available, for example, in COCA, are from news broadcasts. If your intent is to accurately represent colloquial speech, *when abouts* or *whenabouts* may be appropriate. It seems to be common enough in various dialects that [people have questions about it](http://www.englishforums.com/English/AboutAbouts/vlhhc/post.htm), and there are plenty of search results (it seems common in forums).  [When abouts is also used by people on Twitter](http://www.google.com/search?q=when+abouts+site%3Atwitter.com), usually in questions:

> when abouts do you think you will be back?

*When abouts* would not be common where formal register is required. I probably wouldn't even use it in an email; I'd replace it with one of the more commonly written expressions pointed out by @Rachel or @drɱ65 δ. However, I wouldn't be surprised if, walking down the hall, my boss were to ask me, *When abouts do you think you could do that?*

Answer (score 6):

No, *when about* wouldn't sound proper.  *About when* sounds fine; though, not being a world-traveler, I don't know how people in various English-speaking areas will understand it.

> About when do you think you could do that?

Edit: [Ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=About%20when,Around%20when,Approximately%20when&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) reveals a marked preference for *About when* at the beginning of the sentence, when compared with *Approximately when* and *Around when*.

http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=About+when%2CAround+when%2CApproximately+when&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: Perhaps you could write:  **When (about) do you think you could do that?**  But I agree, "About when..." is what I would say.

Comment: "Around when" is more common here, I think.

Comment: Not according to [Ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=About+when%2CAround+when%2CApproximately+when&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 2):

You could just drop the "about" without changing the meaning:

> When do you think you could do that?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative might be - "At what point in time do you think you could do that?"
Another could be - "At what time do you think you could do that?"